# S3 URL encoding when generating Signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a system where after a file is uploaded to S3, a Lambda job raises a queue message and I use it to maintain a list of keys in a MySQL table.

I am trying to generate a pre-signed URL based on the records in my table.

i have two records currently

```
/41jQnjTkg/thumbnail.jpg
/41jQnjTkg/Artist+-+Song.mp3
```

Generating pre-signed URL using :

```
var params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Expires: Settings.UrlGetTimeout,
        Key: record
    };
S3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
```

The URL with `thumbnail.jpg` works perfectly fine, but the one with `+-+` fails. The original file name on local disk was "Artist - Song.mp3". S3 replaced spaces with '+'. Now when I am generating a URL using the exact same filename that S3 uses, it doesn't work; I get a "Specified Key doesn't exist" error from S3.

What must I do to generate URLs consistently for all filenames?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this after a little experimentation.

Instead of directly storing key that S3 provides in their S3 event message, I am first replacing '+' character with space (as they are originally on the disk) and then URL decoding it.

```
return decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\+/img, " "));
```

Now generating a S3 Pre-Signed URL works as expected.

Before MySQL has the following records:

```
/41jQnjTkg/thumbnail.jpg
/41jQnjTkg/Artist+-+Song.mp3
```

Now:

```
/41jQnjTkg/thumbnail.jpg
/41jQnjTkg/Artist - Song.mp3
```

I personally feel there is an inconsistency with S3's api/event messages.

Had i generated a Signed URL directly using the Key that S3 itself provided in SQS event message, It wouldn't have worked. One must do this string replacement step & URL decoding on the key in order to use it to get a proper working url.

Not sure if this is by design or a bug.

Comment: Had the same issue. When getting a SQS notification from S3 event, the s3 object name was encoded, but the sign url wants it decoded.

Answer (score 0):

The second file's name is coming to you [form-urlencoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type). The `+` is actually a space, and if you had other characters (like parenthesis) they would be percent-escaped. You need to run your data through a URL decoder before working with it further.

Side-note: if the only thing your Lambda function does is create an SQS message, you can do that directly from S3 without writing your own function.

Comment: Yes, I should correct my question. I used S3 events to generate a SQS message that i am capturing in my app and processing.